# List of Figures adds vertical space with new Part

Tags: report

I'm trying to remove the vertical space added in the List of Figures when I have new Parts.

This is how I'm removing the vertical space when adding new chapters:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

I was expecting that I might be able to use the same method for eliminating the vertical space for parts, but when I look at the report.cls, I don't find `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}` anywhere in the "Part" section. So I'm not sure where else to remove this space from.

Here is my MWE as well as the preamble for the rest of my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

% including package for figures
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% indent first paragraph
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% change table of contents and list of figures spacing
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]{\addvspace{.7pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[6em]{\addvspace{.4pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[9em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{figure}[2.5em]{\addvspace{.1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{} {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% change spacing of part, chapter, section, and subsection headings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{red}}{Chapter\ \thepart:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{Section\ \thechapter:}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesection}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{black}}{}{5pt}{}   
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{12pt}{0pt}

% remove new page as start of new chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       End Of Preamble and start of document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \part{Part Title}
        Some text in part \thepart.

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Chapter Title}
            Some text in part \thepart chapter \thechapter.
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Chapter Title}
            Some text in part \thepart chapter \thechapter.
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \part{Part Title}
        Some text in part \thepart.

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Chapter Title}
            Some text in part \thepart chapter \thechapter.
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Chapter Title}
            Some text in part \thepart chapter \thechapter.
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
                \caption{Figure in part \thepart\space chapter \thechapter}
            \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of what is being produced. I would like there to be no gap between the "2.2 Figure in part I chapter 2" and "3.1 Figure in part II chapter 3".

[image]

Please give me any suggestions as to where I can remove this extra vertical space from.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to look in the lof-file: The space is created by the command `\ttl@tocsep`, and you can simply redefine it e.g. before the `\listoffigures`:

```
 \makeatletter\def\ttl@tocsep{}\makeatother
```